# How to add column with drop-down list on Django admin change list template?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a TaskRequest model that contains a column named 'owner'. This column contains users from a group named 'owners'.

I want to have an option to select users directly from the change list view without clicking on the task name.

How can I implement a drop-down list so it is visible in the table in my TaskRequest app. Do I really need to overwrite the admin template or is another way to do that?

Comment: You're most likely looking for [list_editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable).

Comment: thanks for the answer and a link, from what I see you can only put BooleanField, CharField, DateField, DateTimeField, IntegerField, ForeignKey or ManyToManyField type of fields. What if I want to use ForeignKey  but display it as drop-down list?

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to @solarissmole I managed to achieve what I needed. In admin.py you just need to put `list_editable = ("owner",)`.